# Actual value in Junits in Epsilon form

Tags: junit, java

In a junit I have, I get the following reason for failure

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<1200000> but was:<1.2E+6>
```

which is essentially the same value. The actual json response is 1200000 when I hit from postman and the method that I am using to get the field for 1200000 has a return type of BigDecimal.

Not sure how to fix this 1.2E+6 as actual.

Answer (score 0):

quite likely you try to compare a BigDecimal to another type and the comparison fail. Please check the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

"true if and only if the specified Object is a BigDecimal whose value and scale are equal to this BigDecimal's."

If the 2 numbers are not BigDecimal, you'll get false. If the 2 are Bigdecimal but don't have the same scale, you should use compareTo.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing that you can do is to compare it using `long` value:

```
assertEquals(new BigDecimal("1.2E+6").longValue(), 1200000);
```

Or you can use `AssertJ` to have a nice and tidy `BigDecimal` assertion:

```
assertThat(new BigDecimal("1.2E+6")).isEqualByComparingTo(new BigDecimal("1200000"));
//or
assertThat(new BigDecimal("1.2E+6")).isEqualByComparingTo("1200000");
```